# How to replace characters inside a string with "*" in C++?

Tags: c++, stdstring

I am new to C++. My task is to replace the last 3 characters of a string variable with `"*"`. The size of string can be variable.

For Example: -  If String `xyz = "123456"` then it should replace 456 with `"***"` and the output string should look like `"123***"`

Comment: **Comment on closure**:  It is possible to tell *exactly* what is being asked given the assumption that we are talking C++ strings.  I'm not commenting on the quality of the question, but I can't figure out how it could be argued that the question is not real.

Answer (score 2):

`xyz.assign(xyz.length(), '*');`

Note that original question was edited to include requirement that only right three characters of string be replaced with '*'.  See my comment below fulfilling this requirement.

Comment: assuming xyz is of type `std::string`.

Comment: "replace the contents of a string variable" - I'd say you're pretty safe with that assumption given the question content.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  Unless user is referring to a char * or char [] as a string?

Comment: thanks alot DWright ... what if i need to mask only last 3 charachters inside my string ? Please can you help me on this

Comment: `xyz.assign(xyz.substring(0,xyz.length()-3)).append(3,'*');`

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::string::replace()`:

```
  string::iterator it = str.begin();   
  str.replace(it,str.end(),str.size(),'*');
```

Comment: Please check the question again. I have edited it. Sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Try similar to this:

this is not compile-checked.

```
for(int i=0; i<strlen(yourString);i++){
   yourString[i]='*';
}
```